# SendKeys.Send() после открытия диспетчера сочетанием Ctrl+Alt+Del не работает

Tags: c#, winapi, клавиатура, keyboardhook

Есть код, который отлавливает все нажатия клавиш глобально через WinApi и не даёт им печататься, а печатает определённый символ, в результате чего получается слово, т.е. я заменяю печатаемые буквы на свои, печатаемые буквы я блокирую, а вместо них отправляю свои через `SendKeys.Send();` Всё работает как надо, при открытии диспетчера из таскбара всё дальше норм работает, но если сочетание клавиш Ctrl+Alt+Delete, тогда печатаемые символы продолжают блокироваться, а мои посылаемые символы не отправляются. Как это исправить? Я пробовал использовать SendKeys.SendWait(), тогда всё норм, но этот метод как то странно работает, то он нормально работает, то отправляет по несколько раз одни и те же символы, а если зажать и держать клавишу вообще ужас печатает. Может с ним можно чё сделать? Пробовал использовать KeyDown из WinApi, тоже всё норм, НО, вообще ни в какую не разобрался как посылать пробелы. Вот если послать один символ - всё норм, если послать один пробел - всё норм, а если символ и за ним пробел - тогда все символы с пробелами печатаются быстро и бесконечно и всё зависает ( с SendInput то же самое ). Помогите чем можете, буду благодарен, запарился уже разбираться

Comment: Я конечно не эксперт,но вроде после KeyDown должен следовать KeyUp. Сочетание дух этих команд как бы говорит что Вы нажали на клавишу и отпустили её. Но я могу ошибаться.

Comment: Ну это само собой разумеется, поэтому я не упоминал этот факт